# How do I retrieve the data of ALL of the users in my nested Firestore database using Ionic4/Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I am trying to retrieve the data of all my users in a nested Firestore database using angular. The data base looks like this users (id) -> posts(id) - 
{ description: this is an image,
image: imageURL} .

I am using a firebase function in this ionic app, and I can successfully get the data of a single user id using this code in the index.ts file.

```
const docs = await
```

admin.firestore().collection('people').doc('R7iR7csLaDZuhUvZJWiFCcaLt903').collection('tasks').limit(5).get()

```
    return docs.docs.map(doc => {
    return {
        postID: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
      }
   }) 
})
```

However this only gets the data of a single file path in the database structure, and I want to retrieve the data of all the docs ID and not just one id.

the home.ts file looks like this

```
constructor(private aff: AngularFireFunctions) {}
 ngOnInit() {

const getFeed = this.aff.httpsCallable('getFeed')
this.posts = getFeed({}).subscribe(data=> {
  console.log(data)
  // this.posts = data
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely will want to normalize your database so you're not making calls into nested collections, if you really want to get all of the posts for all users. To download an entire collection, it would be something like this:

```
const docs = await admin.firestore().collection('people').get()
```

Simply ping the `collection` and not a `document`

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have already tried this method of simply downloading the entire collection but it produces an empty array in the console. I guess I will have to normalize my database